# Maven POM to Ivy Descriptor XSLT

Tags: java, xslt, maven, ivy

Beside's Ivy's built-in `makepom` task, I can't find any (Java-centric) open source projects that specialize in converting a Maven POM file into an Ivy module descriptor.

So I'm thinking that I'm going to have to write an XSLT transform myself, which isn't impossible, it's just more work than I feel is necessary. I'd rather not use `makepom` because that would require invoking Ant/Ivy programmatically (I have a situation where I will be reading the file system for POMs and dynamically-generating their Ivy equivalencies), which just feels wrong.

XSLT just feels like a cleaner solution.

Are there any other tools/frameworks at my dispose here (even other projects that use XSLT for the exact same thing!)? Or am I stuck with this homegrown solution?

Comment: The ivy makepom task works the other way. It reads an ivy file and generates a POM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the [convertpom](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/use/convertpom.html) Ant task ([source](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/ivy/core/trunk/src/java/org/apache/ivy/ant/IvyConvertPom.java)).

I'm not sure I see the problem with invoking Ant programmatically, but you could always just use the [IvyConvertPom](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/ivy/core/trunk/src/java/org/apache/ivy/ant/IvyConvertPom.java) class directly.